# Ball inelastically colliding into a bar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision, torque

> There is a horizontal bar of length $10 \mathbb{m}$ and mass $1 \mathbb{kg}$ that is held up (somehow) in the earths gravitational field. A ball of mass $0.1 \mathbb{kg}$ inelastically collides vertically into the center of the bar from below. The system rises $1 \mathbb{m}$ before dropping. Now the ball inelastically collides (at the same speed) $4 \mathbb{m}$ from the center of the bar (so $1 \mathbb{m}$ from the edge). How high does the$~\rm COM$ of the system rise in this case?

I am stuck between two different ideas. One, the answer is simple because the$~\rm COM$ continues to rise at the same speed in any collision. However, I think this may be wrong because of the rotational aspect of the second case. Two, find the velocity of the ball (simple momentum/energy calculations from the first scenario) and do some sort of conservation of angular momentum analysis, but I have no clue on how to proceed for this case.

Comment: Useful: [this Veritasium video](https://youtu.be/vWVZ6APXM4w), and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of this problem, with the given information, one would use conservation of linear  and angular momentum:  mv = (m + M)V  where the V is for the center of mass of the system, and mvR = Iω where I is the rotational inertia about the center of mass (which is not at the center of the rod), and R is the corrected offset distance.  In a realistic situation, this would not be correct.  The end of the rod beyond the center of mass would try to rotate downward. The reaction force from the point of support in that area would be up. Linear momentum is not conserved, and angular momentum should be calculated about that point of support.